# Shell script to verify docker installation on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, docker, sh, dockerfile

I want to write a shell script which verifies whether docker is installed or not.

If docker is installed:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
$ echo $?
0
```

If docker is not installed:

```
$ docker -v
The program 'docker' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install docker
$ echo $?
127
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker -v
if echo $? = 128 ; then
    echo "The program 'docker' is currently not installed."
else
    echo "Continuing with dockerized way"
fi
```

here for testing purpose, I ran it on the machine where docker is not installed, I kept 127 = 128, condition is wrong, so it should go in else, but still it prints The program 'docker' is currently not installed. I would like to know what I am missing here.

Comment: That will only test that the docker client is installed. If you want to ensure that the daemon is also running, you'll need to use `docker version` instead of just `-v`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
if [ $? -eq 128 ]; then
...
```

To make it even more robust, you might want to check:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
...
```